# Convert date from milliseconds to local timezone

Tags: javascript, time

I create a date like this:

```
var date = new Date(data.nexteventtime * 1000);
```

How can I convert this date from GMT+1 to the local time of the browser?

Comment: Are you saying that your code will provide the milliseconds and you want to take that and convert it to a proper date and display it in the browser? Or are you saying that you need to do a time zone check on the users computer?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using `.getTimezoneOffSet()` This basically will return the difference between UTC Time and local in time (in minutes).

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var offSet = currentDate.getTimezoneOffSet();
```

So if you're time zone is GMT+2 for example, `offSet` will be -120